# How to stop thread without waiting client response

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a "ClientsHandler" class that reads client input and converts it into a server command.
The problem is that when I use the exit command in the server console, runFlag is set to false and the loop starts waiting for the last input from the client before closing the thread. How can I break the loop and stop the thread instantly after exit command?

```
class ClientsHandler(
    private val socket: Socket,
    private val commandManager: CommandManager
) : Runnable {
    companion object {
        var runFlag = true

        fun close() {
            runFlag = false
        }
    }

    override fun run() {
        var input = ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())
        var output = ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())
        var username = (input.readObject() as User).username

        println("$username connected")

        while (runFlag) {
            try {
                var request = input.readObject() as ServerRequest
                output.writeObject(ServerCommandInvoker.invoke(request, commandManager))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("$username disconnected")
                runFlag = false
            }
        }

        input.close()
        output.close()
        socket.close()
    }

}
```

Comment: `class that reads client input` You almost always want to interrupt the thread to stop it.  You have to close these open resources so the right way to do this is to catch the interrupted exception, close resources, then exit.  (That's for Java.  I don't think Kotlin is different, but it might be.  Start there, consult the manual, consult other engineers.)

Comment: Another way would be to close the socket.

Comment: @markspace almost none of that is correct. [1] interrupt does not guarantee that the readObject call stops (on most platforms it does; the spec reserves the right that it doesn't, though), [2] 'then close the resources' is bad practice - you use try-with-resources or a finally block. You do _not_ write close() calls in a catch block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options.

### Interrupt

This is a tricky one, in that the Java library spec explicitly reserves the right for this *not to work*. On most platforms it does work, but you should probably skip it and go for the second option below.

The idea is, `theThreadThatIsCurrentlyBlockingOnTheReadObjectCall.interrupt()` will generally cause that `readObject()` call to exit immediately with an `IOException` whose message states something along the lines of 'thread interrupted'. You can now continue.

The reason this is not guaranteed is because java needs to run on a very wide array of platforms and hardware and perhaps not all of them can do this.

### Just close the socket

Instead, from the thread that is setting the `runFlag` to `false`, you can also just close the socket directly. This *will*, definitely, cause that `readObject()` call that's still running to exit immediately with an `IOException` indicating that the socket is now closed.

Note that your setting of the `runFlag` appears invalid to me, in that it doesn't use `volatile` or `synchronized` or some other mechanism to ensure this field update is actually visible from the other thread reliably. the JVM is free to make that `runFlag` change be visible to your ClientsHandler run method, or not - JVM's choice. So you can't even test that your code is broken.

Generally for purposes like this, you can use an `AtomicBoolean`, which guarantees that writes in one thread are visible to another without a potentially very long delay.